# Can't get rid of a string on explorer.exe (Process Hacker 2)

Tags: string, process

So I did some private navigation on Firefox's Private mode (which shouldn't log anything) and eventually there's a string of something I've searched.
I want it gone, I used Rwipe and clean to get rid of it but no luck, Uninstalled Firefox and all its folders and ran rwipe plus CCleaner this time, no luck.

After that, I also cleared temp and %temp% folder but no luck either.

Funny thing is that I checked Firefox process (before uninstall) and there were no strings of what I searched up in there, those strings of Firefox were on explorer...

I also have prefetch and superfetch disabled. 
I need help, I need those strings gone really quick.. 
Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: This isn't really a programming question...

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm posting this in the wrong website I just didn't know where to post this.

Comment: Try superuser.com - it's another stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

"string on explorer.exe" - not very useful. String where?

Try restarting explorer.exe. Don't do it while Process Hacker is running as administrator though, do it while it's running as standard rights or via Task Manager. If that doesn't work, try rebooting the system.

Either way, an elaboration would be helpful to provide a real solution if either of the above don't resolve the issue.

Comment: [link]http://i.pi.gy/BqZWo.jpg
The strings that say vape are the ones I want to be gone; The ones that say Vape and everything next to it is due to searching with the search everything program.
I just want to get ride of Firefox private browsing strings.

Comment: It's not going away I've restarted it like 1000 times.
explorer.exe just moves from middle list to buttom..

Comment: I've ran R-Wipe and Clean which requires to restart the system after you've wiped everything.

Comment: I've just replicated your scenario and the issue was fixed by restarting explorer.exe...

Comment: I'll record a mini video right now, so you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Bro, I don't know why, but just can't upload anything with my net, this is what I do:
Open PH2, check the strings, restart using task manager, open PH2 again, they're still there..